problems with img tag in angular
I'm trying to loud a jpg logo in angular app, using <img> tag in the HTML of header component. If i click on my path in VS CODE it gets to my image  but on the browser I get error 404.
this is my code:
<div class="logo">
  <img src="/src/assets/2.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 100px; width: 100px">
</div>

I tried playing around with the path, tried to use a relative path but got again 404 un the browser.
I've tried loading through the css, but that hasn't worked,
This is my project structure.

You have missing the app folder in the folder-structure. Change it to /src/app/assets/2.png or ../../assets/2.png

In Angular when you set an image src which is inside the assets folder, you must set it like this:
<div class="logo">
  <img src="assets/2.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 100px; width: 100px">
</div>

The first path part is always without the slash! Then it should be work as well!
